# Unable to access an angularjs module inside another module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

I have an angularJS app with three modules: myApp(parent/core module), services(contains all the factories and services), and controllers(contains all the controllers).

### This is my app.js file

```
angular.module('services', []);
angular.module('controllers', []);
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['services', 'controllers']);
```

I read [here](http://clintberry.com/2013/modular-angularjs-application-design/) that setting up my modules and defining dependencies in this way will allow each of my modules to access the other without having to inject the dependencies.

### Here's my index.html file

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/js/services/testFactory.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controllers/testCtrl.js"></script>
```

### testFactory.js file

```
angular.module('services').factory('testFactory', ['$rootScope', 'apiCall', function($rootScope, apiCall){
    let testFactory = {};

    testFactory.testFunc = function(){
        console.log('testFactory.testFunc called');
    }

    return testFactory;
}])
```

### testCtrl.js file

```
angular.module('controllers').controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', 'testFactory', function($scope, testFactory){
    console.log("inside testCtrl");

    $scope.testing = function(){
        console.log("testing function called");
        testFactory.testFunc();
    }
}])
```

When I call the testFactory.testFunc inside the *myApp* module, it functions correctly. But, when I try calling it in the *controller* module, I'm getting the following error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'testFunc' of undefined

I even tried injecting the *service* module inside the *controller* module as a dependency, but I still got the same error.

How do I get the *service* module to work inside the *controller* module?

Comment: Check for a array-annotation injection missmatch. The names in the injection array should match the arguments in the injected function.

Comment: @georgeawg that solved it. Thanks a ton!